# How do I conditionally buffer key input based on event in RxJs

Tags: javascript, events, rxjs, observable, reactivex

I'm pretty new to RxJs and haven't read a solution to this. More detailed explanation is in the comments, but basically I want to process a key combination (I think buffer would do this) when a specific key is pressed (like pressing "o" will wait for a short time for other keys to be pressed), but immediately process the key input otherwise (anything other than "o" if "o" hasn't been pressed, or the 'timeout' for "o" has passed).

```
Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keydown')
  // Now I want to only continue processing the event if the user pressed "o99" in series,
  // as in pressed "o", followed by "9" and then another "9"
  // I think I can do it with buffer
  .buffer(() => Observable.timer(1000))
  .map((e) => 'option-99')
  // However I need to pass the keys through unbuffered if it's anything but an "o" (unless it is following an "o")
  // In other words, "o99" is buffered or something, but "9" is not, and processed immediately
  .map((e) => e.keyCode)
```

Thanks

Comment: took me a while but cf. my answer which implements the logic with a small state machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a very common case to deal with, which is that of an event whose associated action depends on some control state (i.e. you have a basic state machine). Basically, if you consider those two control states : `SIMPLE_KEY`, `COMBO`, and those two events : `keyup`, and `keyupTimer`, then :

- in the `SIMPLE_KEY` state

  - if the key pressed is `o`, then you switch to `COMBO` state
  - if not `o`, then we remain in same state, and pass the key downstream
  - if timer event, then we pass a null value to be filtered out downstream
- in the `COMBO` state

  - we accumulate key pressed
  - if timer events, then we revert to `SIMPLE_KEY` state

So, to map your event to an action, you need to know the control state you are in. The operator `scan` allows you to decide how to process an event depending on an accumulated state.

It could be something like this (https://jsfiddle.net/cbhmxaas/):

```
function getKeyFromEvent(ev) {return ev.key}
function isKeyPressedIsO(ev) {return getKeyFromEvent(ev) === 'o'}

const KEY = 'key';
const TIMER = 'timer';
const COMBO = 'combo';
const SIMPLE_KEY = 'whatever';
const timeSpanInMs = 1000;
const keyup$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keyup')
  .map(ev => ({event: KEY, data: getKeyFromEvent(ev)}));
const keyupTimer$ = keyup$.flatMapLatest(eventStruct => 
  Rx.Observable.of(eventStruct)
//    .tap(console.warn.bind(console, 'timer event'))
    .delay(timeSpanInMs)
    .map(() => ({event : TIMER, data: null}))
    );

Rx.Observable.merge(keyup$, keyupTimer$)
//  .tap(console.warn.bind(console))
  .scan((acc, eventStruct) => {
    if (acc.control === SIMPLE_KEY) {
      if (eventStruct.event === KEY) {
        if (eventStruct.data === `o`) {
          return {control: COMBO, keyOrKeys : []}
        }
        else {
          return {control: SIMPLE_KEY, keyOrKeys : eventStruct.data}
        }
      }
      else {
      // TIMER event
        return {control: SIMPLE_KEY, keyOrKeys : null}
      }
    }
    else {
      // we only have two states, so it is COMBO state here
      if (eventStruct.event === KEY) {
        return {control: COMBO, keyOrKeys : acc.keyOrKeys.concat([eventStruct.data])}
      }
      else {
        // this is a TIMER event, we only have two events
        return {control: SIMPLE_KEY, keyOrKeys : acc.keyOrKeys}
      }
    }
  }, {control: SIMPLE_KEY, keyOrKeys : null})
//  .tap(console.warn.bind(console))
  .filter(state => state.keyOrKeys) // TIMER event in SIMPLE_KEY state
  .map (({control, keyOrKeys}) => {
  // Here you associate your action
  // if keyOrKeys is an array, then you have a combo
  // else you have a single key
  console.log('key(s) pressed', keyOrKeys)
  return keyOrKeys
})
  .subscribe (console.log.bind(console))
```