# RXJS implement blocking for observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am new on RxJS and angular2, my goal is develop a shared function to prevent racing between model update and saving data to database without using blockui

My rough idea is:

initial state is "unfreeze"

```
1. Parent send "freeze" to children
2. Child components "block" all their internal dom event queues
3. Parent wait for all outstanding async operations (including 
    children) to complete
4. Parent save model data into database
5. Parent send "unfreeze" to children, and child component unblock their queues
```

but do not know how it can be done in RxJS world

(observable) signal -> "freeze"/"unfreeze" from parent component

(observable) target queue ->

```
When "freeze", either (choice of children component)

    a. buffer all events (e.g. keystroke)
    b. drop all events (e.g. mouse click)
    c. keep last event (e.g. windows resize)

    until "unfreeze"

When "unfreeze", no buffering or filtering, forward event ASAP, until "freeze"
```

Thank you very much

Comment: You need to be more specific on what exactly you need or what you are trying to achieve. Based on what you asked, there are many different operators you could use. (buffer, debounce, filter, takeWhile, skipWhile, switchMap, exhaustMap, ...and more...)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43912849/conditional-emission-delays-with-rxjs/43913932#43913932

Comment: You can use [bufferWhen](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-bufferWhen) or bufferToggle.

Comment: edit with more detail

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip values while signal is "freeze"

```js
const signal$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).map(i => i % 2);
const target$ = Rx.Observable.interval(500);
const unfreeze$ = signal$.filter(even => !!even);
const freeeze$ = signal$.filter(even => !even);

target$
  .windowToggle(unfreeze$, () => freeeze$)
  .switch() 
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.0/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to buffer values while it's freezed

```js
const signal$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).map(i => i % 2);
const target$ = Rx.Observable.interval(500).publish();
const unfreeze$ = signal$.filter(odd => odd);

target$.connect();

signal$
  .concatMap(freeze => {
    return freeze
      ? target$.takeUntil(unfreeze$).toArray()
      : target$.takeUntil(signal$);
  })
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.0/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: instead of .switchMap(branch$ => branch$)  you can just do .switch()

Comment: Thanks! I updated the snippet :) ant more thoughts on how to optimize it? ;)

Comment: I agree with windowToggle. Why not to use would say use bufferToggle to buffer?

Comment: If the signal queue do not send any more "freeze" signal after "unfreeze", then the target queue will be "buffered" forever?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bufferToggle

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-bufferToggle

> Collects values from the past as an array. Starts collecting only when opening emits, and calls the closingSelector function to get an Observable that tells when to close the buffer.

```
const start$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('start'), 'click');

const stop$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('stop'),  'click');

const clock$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);

clock$
  .bufferToggle(start$, ()=>stop$)
  .mergeAll()
  .subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

Comment: it seems that "clock" signal cannot pass through until clicking "stop"?