# RxJS: Combine two observables so the observable only emits if the value of the first observable is true

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm currently trying to implement a simple offline/online sync mechanism using observables.

Basically, I have two observables:

1. Connection observable: The first observable gives me the information whether or not there is an internet connections. It emits when the network state changes
2. Data observable: The second observable has the data that needs to synced. It emits when there is new data to be synced

What I want to achieve is to combine the above observables so that:

- As long as the connection state is `false`, the combined observable shouldn't emit. In this case, the data observable should retain its state
- As long as the connection state is `true`, the combined observable should emit every time there is data in the data observable
- If the connection state switches from `false` to `true`, it should emit for every value on the data observable

A small example that currently uses filter and combineLatest can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/offline-sync-s5lv49?file=/src/index.js

Unfortunately, this doesn't behave as intended at all.

Is there any operator to achieve the required behavior? As an alternative, I could maybe poll the connection status of course and emit every X seconds. But ideally, I'd like a clean combination of Observables, though I'm a bit lost with what operator makes most sense.

To clear the idea up: I need to sync all data, not just the latest. So the data observable should buffer the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After also searching for the term "gate", I found the following stack overflow question and post:
[Conditional emission delays with rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43912849/conditional-emission-delays-with-rxjs/54543327#54543327)

Basically, the answer is using delayWhen to achieve the desired result.

I've updated an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/offline-sync-experiments-nimoox?file=/src/index.js:0-1357

The crucial part is:

```
const offlineOnlineSubject = new BehaviorSubject(false);
const dataSubject = new Subject();

const triggerFn = (_) => offlineOnlineSubject.pipe(filter((v) => v));

dataSubject.pipe(delayWhen(triggerFn)).subscribe((counter) => {
  console.log("Syncing data", {
    counter
  });

  syncedIndicator.innerHTML += `<li>${counter}</li>`;
});
```

Wrapped in a custom typescript operator:

```
import { MonoTypeOperatorFunction, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { delayWhen, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

export function gate<T>(gateTrigger: Observable<boolean>): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  const gateTriggerFn = () => gateTrigger.pipe(
    filter((v) => v)
  );

  return (source: Observable<T | null | undefined>) => source.pipe(
    delayWhen(gateTriggerFn)
  );
}
```

It seems so far that this solution is doing what I intend it to do.

Answer (score 2):

So when we are in `offline` mode, I store all the emitted data in a buffer, and once we change from `offline` to `online`, I simply emit everything in the buffer:

```
let dataBuffer = [];
let isPreviouslyOnline = false;

combineLatest([dataSubject, offlineOnlineSubject])
  .pipe(
    filter(([data, isOnline]) => {
      if (!isOnline) {
        if (!isPreviouslyOnline) {
          dataBuffer.push(data);
        }

        isPreviouslyOnline = false;
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    }),
    switchMap(([data]) => {
      isPreviouslyOnline = true;
      if (dataBuffer.length > 0) {
        const tempData = [...dataBuffer];
        dataBuffer = [];

        return from(tempData);
      } else {
        return of(data);
      }
    })
  )
  .subscribe((data) => {
    console.log("Data is: ", data);
  });
```

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/offline-sync-forked-k38kc3?file=/src/index.js

I think it works but it doesn't feel great, was trying to use the native `rxjs` buffer operator to achieve it but couldn't figure out how. Would love to see if anyone has a better/cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that this doesn't feel great. We now have a solution using bufferWhen and two additional Observables, but this doesn't feal great as well. So I'm currently trying to find a solution using the search term "gate" and check what will come up.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like were on the right path and could do just the following:

```
combineLatest([
  offlineOnlineSubject,
  dataSubject
])
  .pipe(
    filter(([online, counter]) => online),
  )
  .subscribe(([online, counter]) => {
    syncedIndicator.textContent = counter;
  });
```

Comment: Using this approach, the latest entry will be synced when going online. But if I emitted 4 elements in the data observable, only the last element will be synced, and the previous elements will be filtered out. I need to sync all the data however.

Comment: So you want to buffer all data emissions while the other Observable is offline?

Comment: Yes, that would be the basic idea.